# Add <br> to an HTML string, BUT leaving HTML properties intact (therefore preserving src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgo [...])

Tags: html, tags

I have an HTML string that looks like this:

```
<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap;margin:0px">Good day,

<span>XXXX</span> rer dsdadad <span>XXX XXXXXX/span> / EER dsadadsd <span >0612</span>ddd <span >ccccccxcx</span>.

Dsdsad d ds dad.

<div id="signature"><br>Regards,

<b>Tony Mobily</b>
XXX XXXXXX
  
<img width="120" height="99" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMoAAACaCAMAAADfNSdtAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJ
bWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyBpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdp
bj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6
eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMC1jMDYwIDYxLjEz
NDc3NywgMjAxMC8wMi8xMi0xNzozMjowMCAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJo
dHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjc==">
<div style="color:rgb(166,166,166);font-family:Calibri,sans-serif,serif;font-size:11pt;margin:0px">
  
  <strong>P:</strong>  + XX X XXXX XXXX
  <strong>F:</strong> + XX X XXXX XXXX
  <strong>M:</strong> +XX XXX XXX XXX
  <strong>E:</strong> rrrrrr@dddddddd.com
  <strong>W:</strong> https://ddddddddd.com
</div>
</pre>
```

It works really well. However, an Exchange plugin apparently deletes ALL of the newlines, without even considering that `<pre>` is a possibility.
So, I need to turn those `\n` into `<br>` elements.

Which is easy -- I know the regexp:

```
  const bodyWithNoNewlines = body.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>')
```

Except, I can't because that will break COMPLETELY the encoded signature.

So, how do I get to add the 
 elements only and only within the HTML itself, keeping HTML properties intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to write this -- I assumed there must be something out there.
Here we go:

```
function newLineToBr (body) {
  const map = {}
  body = body
    .replace(/(<[^>]*>)/g, (match, p1, p2) => {
      const hash = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex')
      map[hash] = match
      return hash
    })
    .replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>')

  for (const key in map) {
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(map, key)) continue
    body = body.replace(key, map[key])
  }

  return body
}
```

I turn ALL tags into placeholders. Then, I convert `\n` into `<br>` -- and THEN I re-replace the placeholders with the original value.

It's a long-winded way of doing it, but it works.

I am VERY OPEN to better answers -- I will only be happy to unmark mine as the answer is something better is added here.

Comment: I have to say, I am absolutely amazed that nobody else asked this, and nobody else found this question/answer pair useful!